# How do I choose which job is featured on my timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I currently work in three places. How can I choose which job appears in my timeline? In my info I have three current jobs and I want to switch the one appearing in the timeline with another one from the remaining two. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without explicitly changing privacy settings for the jobs you don't want to appear, it seems Facebook will choose the most recent job.

Example.

- Job 1: 2009 to present
- Job 2: 2010 to present

Facebook will always choose Job 2

In the case where a user *does not* fill out the start date

- Job 3: (No date shown)

Facebook will *still* choose Job 2

If one were to change this to 2012 to present

Facebook will choose Job 3.

Let me sum it up: **Facebook will choose the job with the smallest time period**. You must add a date to have your most recent job appear featured. In other words the job must appear on the timeline to be your featured job.

[image: Set of test jobs]

[image: Featured Job]

Comment: Not true. I added a more recent job but my earlier acquired job is still featured. Any else know the actual answer if there is one?

Comment: Sorry to hear that but I have extensively tested these flows. You most likely did not add a date to your job.

Comment: No, the answer is right. If Facebook does not recognise the employer (a photo does not show, etc) it will not be the featured Job.

Comment: It's great to see this explained, and it does fit with my own experience. Too bad that we can't control it, though. Did Facebook remove an ability to set privacy options on individual positions? I can only set privacy for my "Work and Education" section as a whole.